# Magento how I refresh block_html cache after product save using programmatically

Tags: magento, caching

I'm trying to refresh Magento cache programmatically after product save / saveandcontinue in admin side .
    I already try

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html');
```

in observer after catalog product save event.I also try

```
foreach($types as $type) {

$c = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);

Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cache_refresh_type', array('type' => $type));
}
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code. It's working. see http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/magento-clear-cache-programmatically/

```
try {
      $type = 'block_html';
      Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);

} catch (Exception $e) {
      Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
```